# Drag and drop into file input doesn't work in IE11

Tags: drag-and-drop

Can anybody answer me: why drag and drop field works fine in chrome and firefox but doesn't work in IE11? IE11 just open the files when I drag and drop them from the desktop.

---

IE version: 11.545.10586.0

---

HTML:

```
<input type="file" />
```

---

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3hc2grcp/.

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer doesn't support drag and drop API of html5 . so you need some kind of library extension.
you must use javascript library such as Dropzone.js. Dropzone.js support drag and drop for files(multiple files also) in even Internet explorer 10+ and 11.

please visit the following URL [here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) .