# HTML input type="file" drag and drop doesnt work in Edge and IE11

Tags: html, angular, file-upload, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I've created a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfjqqe) Angular app where I added only an `input` control to the view. In my project, I created my own *file-uploader* component.
I'm able to drag and drop the file in `Chrome` but cannot do the same thing in `Edge` or `IE11`. I've read [this](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8964523-support-html5-drag-and-drop-of-files-from-explorer) and there was a ticket to add such functionality to Edge. The ticket is marked as completed however the thing still doesn't work for me and based on the comments I'm not the only person. `IE11` is a different story so I need some solution which would work for both browsers.

Is there any smart workaround to this problem in Angular?

Comment: your sample code is working for me and i'm using version: 11.0.9600.19301

Comment: I use IE 11.648.17134.0

Comment: @WenHaoWu I've just found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079542/drag-and-drop-into-file-input-doesnt-work-in-ie11) and it seems that the drag and drop functionality doesn't work also for other versions of IE.

Comment: I am able to produce the issue with MS Edge and IE. I will try to provide feedback to MS Edge engineers regarding this issue. you can use any third party libraries like React-Dropzone as a work around. Ref: https://react-dropzone.js.org/ Besides that I made a test with new Chromium Edge and looks like file drag and drop is working in it. Ref: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/ So in future, We can use the Chromium Edge version which will provide more features and functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML input type=“file” drag and drop don't work in Edge and IE11?

I guess problem is in the polyfills.ts file.

Here have resolved the issue. Here's a link [Working smaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fileupload-control)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Okay, So working fine in Edge. Actually, I have Internet Explorer version 11.437.17763.0. in that is it working fine.

Comment: Clients which use my app have many different versions of Edge and IE so I need some workaround which would work for every version of IE11 and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use a library called **"ngx-file-drop"**. This library provides an Angular directive that allows you to add drag and drop file upload functionality to your application.

To use this library, you first need to install it by running the following command in your terminal:

npm install ngx-file-drop --save